# Apply directive if element has Id or Class (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, conditional-statements

This is a general problem I've run into while trying to learn angular.

> How would you create a directive that only acts on certain elements
>   which have the directive name AND an ID, Class, or other property?
>   Or/Also how might you make a directive that does different things
>   depending upon ID, Class or other properties?

I don't mean the type of thing where you create a directive as a class, and just use `ngClass`. As an example... Imagine a scenario where a user is defining part of the HTML and I can't touch it, but I know that there will be a nav tag with ul's and li's inside of it. How do I make a directive that can be applied to the nav tag that has `id="navi"` without affecting the other nav tags on the page if there are any?

---

To be clear, I come from a jQuery background, so I'm trying to unlearn a lot of bad habits lol. I'm very used to the concept of selecting an element, or a collection of elements via `$` and applying some kind of manipulation or what have you. How can I achieve this type of selective filtering of functionality in a scenario where I'm not able to touch parts of the HTML directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the `element` at hand as well at the attributes of that element within the `link` function. Example concerning you `<nav id="navi">` case:

```
<nav my-directive id="navi"></nav>
```

Directive time!

```
.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (elem[0].id == "navi") {
                //apply specific condition to elem here
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

As you can see, you can check specific properties of the `element` within the link function. `attrs` is an object with all of the elements attributes as well.

Comment: Would I need to use elem[i] and define & iterate i somewhere? or does elem[0] always access whichever element the link function is currently iterating on?

Comment: The index of `0` is just to access the raw HTML element, so you can then call `.id` on it - you can also do `$(elem).attr("id")` (since you come from a jQuery background) - `elem` will ALWAYS be the element that the directive is applied to - if you apply the directive to multiple elements, `elem` will be that instance of the element - no iteration necessary